# How to list the description of all Revision within a Task?

Tags: ruby, rally

Trying to print out Description of all Revisions within a task for a given set of tasks. But `RevisionHistory` seems to be a `HashArray` and not a `RallyObject`. Not sure how to proceed. Any help here would be appreciated. Here is a snippet of the direction I am taking. What should I replace the `------` with?

```
results.each do |task|
  @revisions = task.rally_object['RevisionHistory'].-------
  @revisions.each do |task_revision|
    puts task_revision["Description"]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you shouldn't need to get at the RallyObject there, instead that class was meant to have convenience methods via method missing or [FieldName] to get at the fields for each object.  For example try your loop as:

```
results.each do |task|
  @revisions = task['RevisionHistory']['Revisions']
  #you may need a @revisions = task['RevisionHistory'].read or something like that depending what you fetched in your query.
  @revisions.each do |task_revision|
    puts task_revision["Description"]
  end
end
```

Hope that helps.